# How to link a website to an (Excel) database and build a dropdown menu based on that range?

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I am very new to website building. I have built a simple web app where the user can input his a number and a multiplier, and after clicking "Run" the system will generate the byproduct of the two numbers.

Now I need to add a Username input box and the User Location in the website. 
The database of the username will come from an Excel database that looks like this:
[image]

Then the username input will come as a dropdown menu and the user location will populate automatically based on that username like this:

[image]

I know how to this in Excel, but not in website building.

Anybody can provide any help as to how do this in the website, or maybe incorporate the function in Javascript or HTML? 
PS: the website app is actually a prototype, that's why we want to build the database using Excel. Is it something that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using HTML and javascript. Instead of using Excel, export the Excel sheet into CSV, load the CSV file using AJAX and run your logic in javascript. To ease things you can use JQuery for Ajax and DOM operations.